# Are there any less costly alternatives to Amazon's Relational Database Services (RDS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have the following requirement. I have with me a database containing the **contact** and **address** details of at least 2000 members of my school alumni organization. We want to store all that information in a relation model so that

1. This data can be created and edited on demand.
2. This data is always backed up and should be simple to restore in case the master copy becomes unusable.
3. All sensitive personal information residing in this database is guaranteed to be available only to authorized users.
4. This database won't be online in the first 6 months. It will become online only after a website is built on top of it.

I am not a DBA and I don't want to spend time doing things like backups. I thought Amazon's RDS with it's automatic backup facility was the perfect solution for our needs. The only problem is that being a voluntary organization we cannot spare the monthly $100 to $150 fees this service demands.

So my question is, are there any less costlier alternatives to Amazon's RDS?

Comment: OK - I'd like to ask the same question but in my case I definately need a relational database. Could anyone suggest an alternative for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case of just contact and address data I would choose Amazon SimpleDB. I know SimpleDB might not be suitable for a large number of tables with relationships and all, but for your kind of data I think SimpleDB is sufficient. And costs is much much cheaper than  Amazon RDS.

I also wanted to use RDS, but the smallest db size costs $80 p/month.

Comment: I signed up for the smallest one and was billed over $1,000 for the first month. I'd like to know how you got $80

Comment: Wow that sucks! what db and instance type did you buy? It's 6 years ago. Can't remember where the $80 came from. I checked pricing for MySQL again via [AWS RDS calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#s=RDS) and it's even cheaper.  t1.micro and t2.micro gives 0.00 (dunno why). for t2.small it calculates 24.89 usd  On [AWS RDS pricing list](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/)  it gives $0.017 p/hr for db.t2.micro instance

Comment: $1000/720 = 1.39 p/hr. Could it be you are running a db.m4.4xlarge instance type?

Comment: Connecting from outside is also a factor

Answer (score 3):

With out a bit more info I may be way off base here. but 2000 names addresses etc. is not a large DB and I would have thought that the possible use of Amazons RDS was a bit "overkill" to say the least.

Depending on how (and who) you want view edit etc. there are a number of free or almost free alternatives.

One method may be to set up /use a hosting package that has something like phpMyAdmin linked to a mySQL DB. Doing this it is possible to access and edit etc. the DB without having a website front end.  Not pretty (like a website front end) but practical.  A good host should also back up for you.

Another is to look at Google Documents.  OK not really a database more a spread sheet, but very much on the lines of Excel.  You can share Google docs with invited people and even set up a small website via Google Docs.  This is a free method, but may not be that practical depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks.

I should have mentioned that I have a list of 2000 odd names now, but we plan to grow aggressively over the year and should have by then about 6000 members.

The problem with normal web hosts is their lack of automation like backups. Most of them are also not really transparent as to how they protect sensitive personal information.

Comment: Hi again - OK, I'll still say that 6000 members is a small DB also I think (you don't say) but it appears to only be 1 table.

"protect sensitive personal information" there are numerous ways to do this and not really upto host.  More way DB is designed.  Personally I split information from names and passwords/logings etc. and use a salt field to interconnect connect.
Automation on back ups (for the sizes you are talking about) could be a very simple script - DB backed up every ... or even before every change by creating a simple txt file in a secure folder

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at Microsoft [SQL Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/)?  You can use it free for something like 90 days and then if you only need a 1GB db it would only be about $10 a month.

You mention backup so I thought I would talk about that as well.  They way SQL Azure works is that it automatically creates 2 additional copies of your database on different machines in the data center.  If one of the machines or db's become unavailable it automatically fails over to one of the other db's.

If you need anything above that you can also use the [copy command to backup the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx).

Comment: Do you it? I have around 1billion query per day. Does it charge if query took server resources ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check

http://www.enciva.com/postgresql9-hosting.htm

and

http://www.acugis.com/postgresql-hosting.htm

They work for Postgres and MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

For a frankly tiny db of that size I'd seriously look at http://www.sqlite.org/

it's inprocess, easy to constantly .dump off to S3 and you can use update hooks to keep checkpoints after updates.
backups/restores are almost the equivalent of windows batchfiles and wgets

good encryption using http://sqlcipher.net/

standard OS Filesystem and user level ACLs control security.

running a file backed db makes sense given the fragility of a normal EC2 backed RDBMS to EBS gremlins.

there are exclusions from to SQL92 (no real showstoppers), but given the project cost sensitivity and the RPO and RTO's of an alumni database, I reckon it's a good bet.

Comment: Please don't ever use sqlite for a multi-user web-based application. It's designed for small-scale single user applications only.